# Circular Reveal Android Soften Edges

Tags: android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions, circularreveal

I'm just experimenting with the new Lollipop transitions and was curious if the following was possible. Right now I have a circular reveal animation working beautifully but it reveals the background with a very hard line. I was wondering if it was possible to soften the line or to fade in the edges so that the transition is less harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that using the circular reveal animator. You'd have to make your own to soften the edges, but the performance is likely to be horrible.

The typical circular reveal is very fast and it is difficult to see the hard edges.